# Add characters to specific elements in a list

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list like:

```
['We', 'HELLO', 'want', 'you', 'WOHO', 'self', 'Maybe', 'APIL', 'sort', ...]
```

Now i want to add first word `'We'` something like `'<a>We</a>'` and the same for `'you'` and every third word from now on. So the first word in the list and form then on every third word i want to add `<a></a>`. The same i want for the second word, like `<b></b>`, and again every third word. And, of course, for the third word and then again for every third word after.

I am totally off right now.

I tried to split that big list in a lot of lists with only 3 words each. So i can address the words in the list with [0], [1], [2]. But its unbelievable complicated. Is there a better solution?

I want something like:

```
<a>We</a>
<b>HELLO</b>
<c>want</c>
<a>you</a>
<b>WOHO</b>
<c>self</c>
<a>Maybe</a>
<b>APIL</b>
<c>sort</c>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import itertools

chars = 'abc'
tags = itertools.cycle(chars)
words = ['We', 'HELLO', 'want', 'you', 'WOHO', 'self', 'Maybe', 'APIL', 'sort']

for word, tag in zip(words, tags):
    print("<{0}>{1}</{0}>".format(tag, word))
```

Output:

```
<a>We</a>
<b>HELLO</b>
<c>want</c>
<a>you</a>
<b>WOHO</b>
<c>self</c>
<a>Maybe</a>
<b>APIL</b>
<c>sort</c>
```

Comment: This workes! Big thanks! Is there an easy wayto count that tags? Like `<a1> <a2> ...`?

Comment: I will as soon as the 5 minutes are over!